# Python script truncating directory names

Tags: python, linux, csv, directory

Suppose one has the following script:

```
import csv
import re

#this script is designed to take a list of probe files and
#generate a corresponding swarm file for blasting them against
#some user defined database.

def __main__():
    #args
    infile  = sys.argv[1] #list of sequences to run
    outfile = sys.argv[2] #location of resulting swarm file
    outdir  = sys.argv[3] #location to store results from blast run
    db      = sys.argv[4] #database to query against

    with open(infile) as fi:
        data = [x[0].strip('\n') for x in list(csv.reader(fi))]

    cmd = open(outfile, 'w')
    blast = 'module load blast/2.2.26; blastall -v 5 -b 5 -a 4 -p blastn '
    db = ' -d ' + db


    def f(x):
         input = ' -i ' + str(x)
         out = re.search('(?<=./)([^\/]*)(?=\.)', x).group(0)
         out = ' -o ' + outdir + out + '.out'
         cmd.write(blast + db + input + out + '\n')

    map(f, data)

__main__()
```

If I run it with:

```
python blast-probes.py /data/cornishjp/array-annotations/agilent_4x44k_human/probe-seq-fasta-list.csv ./human.cmd ./ x
```

An example from human.cmd would be:

```
module load blast/2.2.26; blastall -v 5 -b 5 -a 4 -p blastn  -d x -i /data/corni
shjp/array-annotations/agilent_4x44k_human/probe-seqs/A_33_P3344603.fas -o ./A_3
3_P3344603.out
```

If I run it with:

```
python blast-probes.py /data/cornishjp/array-annotations/agilent_4x44k_mouse/probe-seq-fasta-list.csv ./mouse.cmd ./ x
```

An example from mouse.cmd would be:

```
module load blast/2.2.26; blastall -v 5 -b 5 -a 4 -p blastn  -d x -i /data/cornishp/array-annotations/agilent_4x44k_mouse/probe-seqs/A_51_P100327.fas -o ./A_51_P100327.out
```

The difference is when the ending of `agilent_4x44k_` is `human`, the directory is written to file correctly with `cornishjp`. When the ending is `mouse`, the directory is written incorrectly as `cornishp`, the `j` is left out. I've swapped everything around (saving human as mouse.cmd, and so on) and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

The only thing that comes to mind is that when I generate the arguments for the python script, I use tab to autocomplete (linux). Could this be the problem? It is correctly reading the input file, as the script would fail.

Comment: Could you share a few lines of each of the CSV files passed as arg1 (infile)? Could there be a typo in an explicit path within /data/cornishjp/array-annotations/agilent_4x44k_mouse/probe-seq-fasta-list.csv?

Comment: That moment you realize you made a SO post because of a typo...

Comment: So did you figure this out? Post your answer.